# RecyclerView Animate Layout Changes Not Working Fine

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

I have the next structure:

Activity 1:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/FAB_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Activity 2:

```
Form to add new item to the recycler View.
```

XML of the RecyclerView:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:animateLayoutChanges="true"/>
```

I create the item in the second Activity and use startActivityForResult to add the item in the activity one, and then call adapter.notifyItemInserted(0).

The problem is when the item is added, the insert animation does not working properly, but if I don't use the second activity and create the item in the first activity and add to the adapter, it works fine.

¿How can I solve this?

Comment: add the animateLayoutChanges="true" to your main CoordinatorLayout

Comment: I try it, but when the FAB try to disappear and appear later, it does not working properly, it do a "flash"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xml structure might be the problem, check your `layout_behavior`s and use of `CoordinatorLayout`
[Android CoordinatorLayout](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html)

For a nice guide on how to use `CoordinatorLayout` and `layout_behavior` check [this blog](https://lab.getbase.com/introduction-to-coordinator-layout-on-android/)

I've also found that the use of `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` can be very glitchy/buggy in a scrollable `RecyclerView`, I would suggest not using it. For non-scrollable `RecyclerView`s it works fine tho.